# How to attach MySQL database with java application by using Advanced Installer

Tags: java, mysql, easyphp, advanced-installer

I have created a Desktop java application which uses `(EasyPHP) MySQL database`, now I'm trying to create an `EXE` file of the application by using Advanced Installer, I have problem with attaching the database with the exe file.

Can anyone help me how to do that? I have googled it and cant got solution.

Comment: It looks like you use EasyPHP because it comes with a bundled MySQL server, isn't it? But you don't need Apache and PHP neither.
Package and run MySql server in Windows environment is not easy. 

You should Google "bundle/embed mysql server with java application"

Or try to find an alternative, like 100% Java database. Easy to start in the same (or separate) JVM

Comment: Dear @Destroyica thanks for your comment, Yes I'm usingEasyPHP, good recommendation,

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to wrap you jars into executable. Also you can invoke a batch to install the JRE and MySQL

Kindly check my [blog post](http://muhammadhamed.blogspot.com/2013/01/install-mysql-as-windows-service-from.html) which describes how to install MySQL using a batch file

I hope this could help!

Comment: I hope this may help!